# remove stroke from canvas element

Tags: css, canvas, vis.js

vis.js is an open source javascript network visualization library. A nice feature is that it has many useful events you can listen to. One is a right click (i.e. oncontext) event.

However, on a right click chrome adds a blue box around the (canvas) drawing area. This doesn't happen in Firefox or IE.

What css can I add to remove this effect?

A stand alone example can be seen here:
http://visjs.org/examples/network/basicUsage.html

[image: vis.js example of blue box on right click]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the outline from the immediate div around the canvas element.

```
.vis-network {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: it worked! I tried to freeze the browser using dev tools (F12) and hitting F8 when viewing the Sources pane. However, when you freeze the browser, the event disappears so you can't see what is happening. Now it works though.